# How do I retrieve my Tezos from a baker?

Tags: delegating

I have some Tezos in a KT address earning rewards. I can see each of these payments in my Ledger Nano S software, but the principle amount does not exist.

How do I tell Ledger Live about the original balance. My goal is to be able to send the Tezos to a different address (not a new delegator)

Comment: The fact that your tokens are delegated is irrelevant to your question. You keep full ownership of your tokens when you delegate them. They are not locked, you can transfer them at any time.

Comment: The original staked amount does not appear in the Ledger software. And there is no way to input a coin address. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your KT1 against a public chain explorer like tzstats.com or tzkt.io. Do you see the entire balance there? If so, then LL has the problem and you should open a support issue with them.

You can transfer funds out of your KT1 at any time.

Comment: It does exist on the chain. Problem is with LL. Thank you